# How does React hook handle dependency lists when passing objects to child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Parent component like this:

```
function ParentComponent(){
  return (
    <ChildComponent data={{ x: 1, y: 2 }} />
  )
}
```

Child component like this:

```
function ChildComponent({ data }){
  const [sum, set] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    set(data.x + data.y)
  }, [data])

  return (
    <div>{sum}</div>
  )
}
```

If it is like the above method, it will cause repeated rendering between subgroups, because the data is always changing. How should I deal with such a scenario?

Of course I know it's possible to cache data in the parent component by `const [data] = useState({ x: 1, y: 2 })`, but I want to know if there is a better solution, if any object parameter is required useState to cache, is this implementation too complicated?

In addition, it can also be stored in the child component through `const dataRef = useRef(data)`, but if a value of data changes, it will not be recalculated.

Other parameters such as functions and arrays are the same.

What's wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

> if any object parameter is required useState to cache

Luckily, the dependency array can contain *any* value - not just objects. Because you're using what's being passed down as

```
set(data.x + data.y)
```

you could set the dependency array to *just those properties*, rather than the whole object:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    set(data.x + data.y)
  }, [data.x, data.y])
```

or even

```
  useEffect(() => {
    set(data.x + data.y)
  }, [data.x + data.y])
```

Alternatively - in React, when you want to keep things in sync, it's often easier (and cleaner) *not* to duplicate state / props in multiple components when possible. For example, if something's being passed down as a prop, if you can *just use the prop*, rather than also putting the prop into state, that can be the easier approach than the alternative. I know this was just a toy example, but it's not an uncommon pitfall.

```
function ChildComponent({ data }){
  return (
    <div>{data.x + data.y}</div>
  )
}
```

(If the operation to be performed is expensive, and you don't want to perform it on every render, memoize the value instead of putting it into state)